# Is it possible to draw a transparent layer without using Image?-LibGdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

In my game, when I click a button, popup will come out.

At the same time,I want to draw a transparent layer over the screen except popup, to make an impression like while popup is active,background is disabled.

Something like this:

[image]

Is it possible to make an existing solid image to create a transparent overlay ?

or

I should use a transparent image itself to make the impression of transparent layer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Image` is an `Actor` that can be drawn but you need transparency for your actor, use `Actor`.

Create an `Actor` as transparent layer and add in proper order so that you can disable touch for background actor only.

**You should maintain order of Actors.**

```
stage=new Stage();
Texture texture=new Texture("badlogic.jpg");

Image image=new Image(texture);
image.addListener(new ClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                Gdx.app.log("TouchTest","Clicked on Image");
            }
        });

stage.addActor(image);

Actor actor=new Actor();   // this is your transparent layer 
actor.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
stage.addActor(actor);

// Popup should on the top or your actor(touch layer) 

Image image1=new Image(texture);
image.setPosition(100,100);
stage.addActor(image1);

Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

You can also manage touchability of your touch layer.

```
actor.setTouchable(Touchable.disabled);  // when you want to disable touch on
```

---

In my suggestion you should use `Dialog` for your popup.  Dialog is a modal window containing a content table.

**EDIT**

From your reference image it's seems that you need semi-transparent layer so use `semiTL` instead of `Actor` in above code.

```
Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(1,1, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
pixmap.setColor(Color.BLACK);
pixmap.fillRectangle(0, 0, 1, 1);
Texture texture1=new Texture(pixmap);
pixmap.dispose();

Image semiTL=new Image(texture1);
semiTL.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
semiTL.getColor().a=.8f;
stage.addActor(semiTL);
```

Comment: Thank you.The answer is informative for creating a layer.But actually my question was about creating a transparent overlay from an existing image.May be my question is not clear.Now edited to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

As Abhishek Aryan said, you can use Pixmap to create the sized foundation for your background. But instead of using an image, you can use sprite and sprite drawable like this

```
private Drawable getStageBackground() {
    Pixmap stageBg = new Pixmap(
            Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),
            Gdx.graphics.getHeight(),
            Pixmap.Format.RGB888);

    Sprite image = new Sprite(new Texture(stageBg));
    image.setColor(1, 1, 1, 0.7f);

    return new SpriteDrawable(image);
}
```

And pass this drawable in your dialog window style with stageBackground property like this

```
Window.WindowStyle style = new Window.WindowStyle();
style.stageBackground = getStageBackground();
```